# Marklogic field search options

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am having search options like the following

```
let $options :=
 <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="collection">
        <collection prefix=""/>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="concept_name">
        <word>
            <field name="concept_name" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1"/>
        </word>
    </constraint>
    <term>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
    <return-facets>false</return-facets>
    <return-values>false</return-values>
    <return-constraints>false</return-constraints>
    <return-frequencies>false</return-frequencies>
    <return-qtext>false</return-qtext>
    <search-option>format-json</search-option>
    <search-option>score-simple</search-option>
</options>
```

And doing the search `search:search($q, $options, $start, $page-length)`

But the search is **not doing** `case-insensitive`. How do I tell in this scenario to specify options for a `field`.. I want it to be  `case-insensitive`

When I do 
`cts:field-value-match("concept_name", $q ("case-insensitive", "diacritic-insensitive"))` , I do get the correct results, so how do I specify using the search options like above to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your `<term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>` inside your `<constraint...><word>` element.  That way the option affects your search with that constraint.  However, you haven't shared your `$q` (serach string), so I don't know for sure what search you're testing with.

You should note that `cts:field-word-match` will search in the field word lexicon and is therefore a better fit for what you're doing with your search:search than `cts:field-value-match` which matches the values in the field range index.

In any case, I'm not sure what your options are on your database or field, so it's not clear why you're struggling to get case-insensitive matches.  When I try `cts:field-word-match("concept_name", "alexa488", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1"))` I get a match even though I didn't add the `case-insensitive` option.  Similarly, when I try the search:search with no `<term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>` I get a match.

Comment: I have 
stemmed searches: basic, word searches, field value searches, field value positions, fast phrase searches, trailing wildcard searches, trailing wildcard word positions, three character searches` turned on
I also added the term options inside the constraint and same issue.. Funny thing is doing cts: works but `search:` does not..